# How can I get value from data-bind in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Is it possible to get actual value from the input, while using knockout js on frontend, like:

```
<input type="text" id="messageTitle" data-autocomplete="title" data-bind="value: XY.messageEdit.viewModel().message.title">
```

to reuse it later in the jmeter test?

I believe regexp or xpath are not a valid solutions, cause we can't see true value in the response source code (but its JS representation)

Comment: What sampler are you using? Is that regular HTTP Sampler?

Comment: @YuriG yes, `Add -> Sampler -> HTTP Request` and I'm trying different Post-processors, however without luck so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, the HTTP sampler only executes HTTP protocol per se - it does some parsing for embedded resources, but doesn't execute all bells & whistles.

Hence, you're using the wrong Sampler.

The one you need is most likely a [WebDriver sampler](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins-webdriver) which would simulate the browser behavior for you.

Check out these two articles on the subject: 
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler/
and 
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered/